# how to read text from notepad and store it without any duplicates?

Tags: java, string, text, split

I'm having a text file with the texts like this

> 67 #SUPPORT: 5
>
> 67 76 #SUPPORT: 10
>
> 76 #SUPPORT: 10

here the item 67 and 76 occurs two times, i need to take these two values to my mysql database for further processing.
I tried with HashMap and other things but it is not working for me. Need some help here!!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do here. item 67 and 76 do not obviously occur two times, and in any case the two are not identical, so how do you decide which is the true value, and which to discard?

Comment: Could you share your attempt with the Hash Map and explain what isn't working?

Comment: do you have any tried code ?

Comment: The first line has single occurrence of 67, second line has another occurrence, hence the count becomes two. Same as for 76.

Answer (score -2):

you can use set which won't allow duplicates

```
int count[] = {67, 22,76,22,30,76};

    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

    try{
       for(int i = 0; i<5; i++){
          set.add(count[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(set);
```

result: [22, 67, 76, 30]